# How to make recursive formula for algorithm

Tags: python, recursion

I've got two lists of words. I want to check if the first word from listA is in listB, then second word from listA is in listB, and so on. If a word is present, I increment some integer variable. I have to do it with recursive function `isWordInArray` which takes 2 arguments: `listA` and `listB`

I've tried to do something like this,but I have no idea if it's correct :

```
isWordInArray(listA, listB) = isWordInArray(listA[i] in listB)
```

Comment: Is this an assignment ?. Even if it so can you care to show what you have done. With sample input and output ?.

Comment: It's just a formula. For example **input**
`listA=["dog","is","black"]
listB=["my","cat","is","white"]`
**output 1**
My recursive function should return 1,because only _"is"_ appears in both lists.What I haven't mentioned is that I will remove that word from both lists.

Comment: Do you need a recursive function or normal funtion would do ?.

Comment: I need a recursive function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited after I saw your comment clarifying what you are trying to do.

Maybe something like:

```
index = 0

def isWordInArray(listA, listB):
    global index
    if index < len(listA):
        if listA[index] in listB:
            item_to_remove = listA[index]
            listA.remove(item_to_remove)
            listB.remove(item_to_remove)
            print "Removed {}".format(item_to_remove)
        else:
            index += 1

        isWordInArray(listA, listB)
```

Comment: I think there is a little misunderstanding.I just want to check if the current value is in listB.For example,let's say input is
`listA=["i","have","a","white","cat"]
 listB=["this","cat","is","white"]`
Output 2
I check the first word from listA with every word from listB,if they are same,I increment variable and I also remove words from both lists.If it should be done "normal way",it would be:
`for i in listA:
    if i in listB:
        num+=1
        listB.remove(i)
        listA.remove(i)
`

Comment: I edited my answer above. Hopefully that's more what you are looking for.

Comment: I think you forgot to **return** `isWordInArray(listA, listB)` .But compiler returns error because of index.I think it should be global variable,or am I wrong?

Comment: Right. I'm always thinking in terms of class definitions. Edited.

Comment: There's no need to return any results in this case, however, because Python passes the parameters by reference. So modifications to the array in the function affect the array reference. So if you add a print after executing the function you'll see your original arrays have been modified.

Comment: Sorry about all the edits. I had just modified the original but it had a flaw because of the original logic.

Comment: @H.Hasin If this is you selected answer please mark it as the answer. Thanks!